# C++ make error

Tags: c++, cmake

https://github.com/hntuan94/libPySeek

このドキュメントに従い進めていたところ，`make` を実行時にエラーが出たのですが，これは何が原因なのか分かりません．
文字数制限で詳細が載せられないですすいません．

Windows10 WSL環境 VSCode
No such file or directory みたいなエラーは解決しました．

```
saino@DESKTOP-KR80A41:/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/build$ cmake ../
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (found version "3.6.9") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (found suitable version "3.6.9", minimum required is "2") 
-- SRC: SeekCam.cpp;SeekDevice.cpp;thSeekThermalPro.cpp;pyseek.cpp;conversion.cpp;np_opencv_converter.cpp;SeekCam.h;SeekDevice.h;SeekLogging.h;thSeekThermalPro.h;container.h;conversion.h;template.h;np_opencv_converter.hpp
-- OpenCV_LIBS: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_gapi;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_stitching;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_aruco;opencv_barcode;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_datasets;opencv_dnn_objdetect;opencv_dnn_superres;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hfs;opencv_img_hash;opencv_intensity_transform;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_mcc;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_quality;opencv_rapid;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_shape;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_superres;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_videostab;opencv_wechat_qrcode;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto
-- CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR: /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src
-- OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/local/include/opencv4
-- Boost_INCLUDE_DIR: /home/rnd/boost_1_66_0
-- PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/include/python3.6m
-- numpy_include: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
-- OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/local/include/opencv4
-- OpenCV_LIBRARIES: opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_gapi;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_stitching;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_aruco;opencv_barcode;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_ccalib;opencv_datasets;opencv_dnn_objdetect;opencv_dnn_superres;opencv_dpm;opencv_face;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_hfs;opencv_img_hash;opencv_intensity_transform;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_mcc;opencv_optflow;opencv_phase_unwrapping;opencv_plot;opencv_quality;opencv_rapid;opencv_reg;opencv_rgbd;opencv_saliency;opencv_shape;opencv_stereo;opencv_structured_light;opencv_superres;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_text;opencv_tracking;opencv_videostab;opencv_wechat_qrcode;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_xphoto
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/build
saino@DESKTOP-KR80A41:/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/build$ make
[  4%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/pyseek.dir/conversion.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822: 
,
                 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,  
                 from /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.h:10,
                 from /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:4:
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
  ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/sched.h:29:0,
                 from /usr/include/pthread.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/array:39,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:746,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:52,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.h:8,
                 from /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:4:
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp: In function ‘void init()’:
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1531:151: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
 rr_Print(); PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, "numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"); return NULL; } }                                                                                                  ^        
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:12:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘import_array’
     import_array();
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp: In member function ‘cv::UMatData* NumpyAllocator::allocate(int, const int*, int, void*, size_t*, int, cv::UMatUsageFlags) const’:
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:94:16: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]    
   USAGE_DEFAULT;
                ^
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:99:92: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘cv::AccessFlag’ [-fpermissive]
             return stdAllocator->allocate(dims0, sizes, type, data, step, flags, usageFlags);
                                                                                            ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:58:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.h:8,
                 from /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:479:23: note:   initializing argument 6 of ‘virtual cv::UMatData* cv::MatAllocator::allocate(int, const int*, int, void*, size_t*, cv::AccessFlag, cv::UMatUsageFlags) const’
     virtual UMatData* allocate(int dims, const int* sizes, int type,
                       ^~~~~~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp: In member function ‘bool NumpyAllocator::allocate(cv::UMatData*, int, cv::UMatUsageFlags) const’:
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:124:59: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘cv::AccessFlag’ [-fpermissive]
   return stdAllocator->allocate(u, accessFlags, usageFlags);
                                                           ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:58:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.h:8,
                 from /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:481:18: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘virtual bool cv::MatAllocator::allocate(cv::UMatData*, cv::AccessFlag, cv::UMatUsageFlags) const’
     virtual bool allocate(UMatData* data, AccessFlag accessflags, UMatUsageFlags usageFlags) const = 0;   
                  ^~~~~~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp: At global scope:
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:194:16: error: cannot declare variable ‘g_numpyAllocator’ to be of abstract type ‘NumpyAllocator’
 NumpyAllocator g_numpyAllocator;
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:73:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘NumpyAllocator’:
 class NumpyAllocator : public MatAllocator
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:58:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.h:8,
                 from /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:479:23: note:   virtual cv::UMatData* cv::MatAllocator::allocate(int, const int*, int, void*, size_t*, cv::AccessFlag, cv::UMatUsageFlags) const
     virtual UMatData* allocate(int dims, const int* sizes, int type,
                       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:481:18: note:   virtual bool cv::MatAllocator::allocate(cv::UMatData*, cv::AccessFlag, cv::UMatUsageFlags) const
     virtual bool allocate(UMatData* data, AccessFlag accessflags, UMatUsageFlags usageFlags) const = 0;   
                  ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/sched.h:29:0,
                 from /usr/include/pthread.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr.h:148,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ext/atomicity.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/string:52,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/array:39,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:746,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:52,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52,
                 from /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.h:8,
                 from /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:4:
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp: In member function ‘void NDArrayConverter::init()’:        
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1531:151: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
 rr_Print(); PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, "numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"); return NULL; } }                                                                                                  ^        
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:200:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘import_array’
     import_array();
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp: In member function ‘cv::Mat NDArrayConverter::toMat(const PyObject*)’:
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:233:17: error: ‘CV_MAX_DIM’ was not declared in this scope  
     if(ndims >= CV_MAX_DIM)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:233:17: note: suggested alternative: ‘CV_MAT_CN’
     if(ndims >= CV_MAX_DIM)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
                 CV_MAT_CN
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:238:14: error: ‘CV_MAX_DIM’ was not declared in this scope  
     int size[CV_MAX_DIM+1];
              ^~~~~~~~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:238:14: note: suggested alternative: ‘CV_MAT_CN’
     int size[CV_MAX_DIM+1];
              ^~~~~~~~~~
              CV_MAT_CN
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:246:9: error: ‘size’ was not declared in this scope
         size[i] = (int)_sizes[i];
         ^~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:246:9: note: suggested alternative: ‘dysize’
         size[i] = (int)_sizes[i];
         ^~~~
         dysize
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:247:9: error: ‘step’ was not declared in this scope
         step[i] = (size_t)_strides[i];
         ^~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:247:9: note: suggested alternative: ‘stat’
         step[i] = (size_t)_strides[i];
         ^~~~
         stat
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:250:23: error: ‘step’ was not declared in this scope        
     if( ndims == 0 || step[ndims-1] > elemsize ) {
                       ^~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:250:23: note: suggested alternative: ‘stat’
     if( ndims == 0 || step[ndims-1] > elemsize ) {
                       ^~~~
                       stat
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:251:9: error: ‘size’ was not declared in this scope
         size[ndims] = 1;
         ^~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:251:9: note: suggested alternative: ‘dysize’
         size[ndims] = 1;
         ^~~~
         dysize
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:256:23: error: ‘step’ was not declared in this scope        
     if( ndims >= 2 && step[0] < step[1] )
                       ^~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:256:23: note: suggested alternative: ‘stat’
     if( ndims >= 2 && step[0] < step[1] )
                       ^~~~
                       stat
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:258:19: error: ‘size’ was not declared in this scope        
         std::swap(size[0], size[1]);
                   ^~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:258:19: note: suggested alternative: ‘dysize’
         std::swap(size[0], size[1]);
                   ^~~~
                   dysize
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:271:23: error: ‘size’ was not declared in this scope        
     if( ndims == 3 && size[2] <= CV_CN_MAX && step[1] == elemsize*size[2] )
                       ^~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:271:23: note: suggested alternative: ‘dysize’
     if( ndims == 3 && size[2] <= CV_CN_MAX && step[1] == elemsize*size[2] )
                       ^~~~
                       dysize
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:271:47: error: ‘step’ was not declared in this scope        
     if( ndims == 3 && size[2] <= CV_CN_MAX && step[1] == elemsize*size[2] )
                                               ^~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:271:47: note: suggested alternative: ‘stat’
     if( ndims == 3 && size[2] <= CV_CN_MAX && step[1] == elemsize*size[2] )
                                               ^~~~
                                               stat
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:283:20: error: ‘size’ was not declared in this scope        
     m = Mat(ndims, size, type, PyArray_DATA(o), step);
                    ^~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:283:20: note: suggested alternative: ‘dysize’
     m = Mat(ndims, size, type, PyArray_DATA(o), step);
                    ^~~~
                    dysize
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:283:49: error: ‘step’ was not declared in this scope        
     m = Mat(ndims, size, type, PyArray_DATA(o), step);
                                                 ^~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:283:49: note: suggested alternative: ‘stat’
     m = Mat(ndims, size, type, PyArray_DATA(o), step);
                                                 ^~~~
                                                 stat
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp: At global scope:
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:53:18: warning: ‘PyObject* failmsgp(const char*, ...)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static PyObject* failmsgp(const char *fmt, ...)
                  ^~~~~~~~
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:10:13: warning: ‘void init()’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void init()
             ^~~~
In file included from /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.cpp:4:0:
/mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/src/conversion.h:12:18: warning: ‘opencv_error’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static PyObject* opencv_error = 0;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/CMakeFiles/pyseek.dir/build.make:158: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/pyseek.dir/conversion.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/pyseek.dir/conversion.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:89: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/pyseek.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/pyseek.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

※Makefileを追加しました
Makefile

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.10

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:


#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache

.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "No interactive CMake dialog available..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -E echo No\ interactive\ CMake\ dialog\ available.
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache

.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/build/CMakeFiles /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /mnt/d/study_data/libPySeek/build/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean

.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named pyseek

# Build rule for target.
pyseek: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 pyseek
.PHONY : pyseek

# fast build rule for target.
pyseek/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f src/CMakeFiles/pyseek.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/pyseek.dir/build
.PHONY : pyseek/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named thSeekThermalPro_static

# Build rule for target.
thSeekThermalPro_static: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 thSeekThermalPro_static
.PHONY : thSeekThermalPro_static

# fast build rule for target.
thSeekThermalPro_static/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f src/CMakeFiles/thSeekThermalPro_static.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/thSeekThermalPro_static.dir/build
.PHONY : thSeekThermalPro_static/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named thSeekThermalPro

# Build rule for target.
thSeekThermalPro: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 thSeekThermalPro
.PHONY : thSeekThermalPro

# fast build rule for target.
thSeekThermalPro/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f src/CMakeFiles/thSeekThermalPro.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/thSeekThermalPro.dir/build
.PHONY : thSeekThermalPro/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named seek_test_pro

# Build rule for target.
seek_test_pro: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 seek_test_pro
.PHONY : seek_test_pro

# fast build rule for target.
seek_test_pro/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f example/CMakeFiles/seek_test_pro.dir/build.make example/CMakeFiles/seek_test_pro.dir/build
.PHONY : seek_test_pro/fast

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... pyseek"
    @echo "... thSeekThermalPro_static"
    @echo "... thSeekThermalPro"
    @echo "... seek_test_pro"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

Comment: エラーメッセージ(error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive])によれば、CXXFLAGS に `-fpermissive` を追加する事でエラーを回避する事ができるかと思います。参考:[Error when compiling (python 3.6) · Issue #8 · chrischoy/knn_cuda](https://github.com/chrischoy/knn_cuda/issues/8)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．こちらの参考文献を読んだところ，Makefile の CXXFLAGS に -fpermissive を以下のように追加する
```CXXFLAGS := -fPIC -fpermissive```  と書かれていました．Makefile は build フォルダ内にありましたが，CXXFLAGSの文字列が見当たりません．どこに挿入したらよいでしょうか．(Makefileの詳細を載せていなかったので載せておきました)

Comment: build/src/CMakeFiles/pyseek.dir/flags.make の ```CXX_FLAGS = ``` のところに```-fpermissive```を追加したところ，このエラーは解決しました．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build/src/CMakeFiles/pyseek.dir/flags.make の CXX_FLAGS =  のところに-fpermissiveを追加したところ，このエラーは解決しました．